# Wordpress force user to login before view any site content

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication

In wordpress I am trying to force user login first before see anything. Means I want my user to first login to view any single page, post or archive and only they can se FAQ page. I am trying with below code but problem is as soon as I loged in, its redirect me again to login page.

However my site structure would be like below and in same manner I want this code to work...

```
// Force user to login on welcome
function my_force_login() {
global $post;

    if (is_single() || is_front_page() || is_page() && !is_page('login') && !is_user_logged_in()){ 
        auth_redirect(); 
    }   
}
```

Welcomd-Login screen (like facebook)
-Home page
-Blog
-About
-contact
-FAQ

So I want to allow visitor only can see Welcome Login screen and FAQ, contact page to view rest of the site I want to force them to login..

I need great help of you people.. Thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are missing a parenthesis:

```
if ( ( is_single() || is_front_page() || is_page() ) 
       && !is_page('login') && !is_user_logged_in()){ 
    auth_redirect(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like charm. I have just added is_archive() to prevent category and archive list.

Thanks a lot. I will come back if need some more help for the same.. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin you can use for this. [Private Only](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/private-only/)

Comment: Privet Only will work if I want to use wp-login.php and not my own login page. Here I want to use login screen as my theme login screen so I am using `!is_page('login')` That plugin is keep going on n on in redirecting loop.. Because I have my own redirects after login and etc..

Comment: Thank you .. exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Easy way

```
// Require login for site
get_currentuserinfo();
global $user_ID;
if ($user_ID == '') { 
  header('Location: /wp-login.php'); exit(); 
}
```

Comment: Seems limited. You can only use this on templates, not sitewide since it could cause a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work pretty well for me.

```
function _nok_force_user_login() {
    if ( !is_page('login') && !is_user_logged_in() ){ 
        auth_redirect(); 
    } 
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', '_nok_force_user_login' );
```